# Expression help for Find and Replace in Notepad++

Tags: microsoft-word, notepad++, regex

I'm fuddling my way through using regular expressions in notepad++ with some .xml files, and may have gotten a little over my head.

I'm currently trying to search for anything that starts with:

```
<text id="name">Timer</text>   (where "Timer" is a random word\s)
```

and replace with

```
<text id="name">Timer</text><text id="MyRule">1.rule</text>
```

**1.rule** would be used in all follow up instances of the search, the only random factor is the word between the id=name and the close of the text.

Another Example would be:

```
<text id="name">start up changes</text>
```

and i'm looking to replace to

```
 <text id="name">start up changes</text><text id="MyRule">1.rule</text>
```

Is there a simple regular expression that can find these random word or words, and then apply my changes after that expression. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Karan's case will work.  However, it's also a bit risky -- you'll also get replacements for the following:

```
<text id="Spatula">Um, how about kitchen utensils for $500, Alex?</text>
<text rex="a" expl="something" other_att="1">"Blasphemy!" he shouted, as he ran to the gondola.</text>
```

If you *only* want to catch those instances of `<text>` tags that only have `id="name"` attributes, and your file might have other content, then be specific:

Search:

```
(<text id="name">.*?</text>)
```

Replace:

```
\1<text id="MyRule">1.rule</text>
```

#### Note

If your sample content is intended to be XML or HTML, be aware that `id` values are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to NotePad++ right now to double-check, but try the following:

Search: `(<text.*?/text>)`

Replace: `\1<text id="MyRule">1.rule</text>`